# Группировка многомерного массива с array_combine

Tags: php

Имеется два массива.

Ключи - `$keys = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'];`

Значения -

```
$values = [
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Apple'],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Ball'],
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Bridge'],
            ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Color'],
        ];
```

Когда я пытаюсь объединить эти два массива с помощью array_combine, я получаю такой результат. То есть, значение с id = 2 теряется.

```
 [
    'a' => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Apple'],
    'b' => ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Bridge'],
    'c' => ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Color'],
];
```

Могу я каким-то образом получить результат такого вида?

```
[
    'a' => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Apple'],
    'b' => [
        0 => ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Ball'],
        1 => ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Bridge'],
        ],
    'c' => ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Color'],
];
```

Comment: Вопрос дублирует уже имеющийся ответ на английской версии. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377575/array-multidimensional-if-array-combine-has-duplicated-key

Comment: вы хорошо подумали, как вы свой этот результат в дальнейшем будете обрабатывать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение "в лоб":

```
// Подсчитываем количество одинаковых ключей в массиве ключей $keys.
// Это нужно для того, чтобы определить сколько элементов 
// в массиве значений $values соответствует каждому ключу
$count = array_count_values($keys);
$result = [];    
// Далее проходим по всем ключам из массива ключей $keys
foreach ($keys as $index => $key) {
    if ($count[$key] === 1) {
        // Если очередному ключу $key соответствует 
        // только один элемент из массива значений $values,
        // то присваиваем этот элемент по ключу $key
        $result[$key] = $values[$index];
    } else {
        // Если очередному ключу $key соответствует 
        // несколько элементов из массива значений $values,
        // то добавляем этот элемент в массив
        $result[$key][] = $values[$index];
    }
}
```

Решение предполагает, что количество элементов в массиве ключей `$keys` равно количеству элементов массива значений `$values`.